# Trying to delete an object from Arraylist - still possible to access object

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm trying to add function to delete objects from my array list (first i want to generate unique random ids for these objects:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Medium {
    public Medium(){
        this.id = generateID();
        System.out.println("ID: " + id);
        mlist.add(this);
    }

    protected int generateID() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int id;
        do {
            id = 100 + (random.nextInt(999-100));
        } while(idlist.contains(id));
         idlist.add(id);
        return id;
          }

    protected boolean delete(Medium delElem) {
        boolean isDeleted = false;
        ListIterator<Medium> it = mlist.listIterator(); 
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                it = mlist.listIterator();
                Medium next = it.next();
                if(delElem.getID() == next.getID()) {
                    delElem = next;
                    mlist.remove(delElem);
                    delElem = null;
                    if(delElem == null) {
                        System.out.println("Succesfull deleted");
                    }
                    isDeleted = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }
        return isDeleted;
        }
        protected int getID() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }


    protected ArrayList<Medium> mlist = new ArrayList<Medium>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> idlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    protected String title;
    protected final int id;
}
```

I'm not sure if i understand this properly, but if i set the delElem = the object that meets the equal id, delete my object and set it = null, the object should not reference anymore. But if I test it in my main function, for example book.getTitle(), the title will be printed. I think it's because it's just a local object in my function. How can I globally delete my object in a function and return a boolean value if the object was removed succesfully?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we need more context, and from where do you have the `mlist`?

Comment: better than put all the code in here is to edit your post with the extra info

Comment: What does it matter? As soon as it has no references it's eligible for GC. If there goal is to remove it from the list it sends like you're already done.

Comment: I agree with Dave. Explicitely deleting objects is something you usually do not do in Java. You remove the references where they do not belong any more, and once an object is no longer referenced, it becomes eligible for garbage collection and might vanish from memory or not, who cares. But since you apparently keep a reference in your main method, that will not happen.

Comment: hm ok i thought if i remove the object from my list and declare it as null, the attributes shouldn't be still accessible. But i understand that this couldn't be possible globally in this way.

Comment: There are fundamental problems with your code. Each `Medium` has it's own `ArrayList<Medium>`, for example. I _think_ this is causing your errors.

Comment: Thanks for your input, can you help me how to implement array list best way? each medium (book, magazine, article) should automatically added to an arraylist when initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has already been stated in the comments that you usually don't delete objects manually (by setting them to null). The garbage collection will do it's job when they are not needed anymore.

The weird thing in your code is that the medium adds itself to the list. Why don't you create another class that represents a book shelf. This way you can implement methods on the bookshelf to add or remove books:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class BookShelf {

    protected ArrayList<Medium> mlist = new ArrayList<Medium>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> idlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private class Medium {
        protected int id;
        protected String title;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

    public Medium addMedium(String title) {
        Medium medium = new Medium();
        medium.setId(this.generateID());
        medium.setTitle(title);
        this.mlist.add(medium);
        return medium;
    }

    protected int generateID() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int id;
        do {
            id = 100 + (random.nextInt(999 - 100));
        } while (idlist.contains(id));
        idlist.add(id);
        return id;
    }

    protected boolean delete(Medium delElem) {
        boolean isDeleted = false;
        for (Medium medium : mlist) {
            if (medium.getId() == delElem.getId()) {
                mlist.remove(medium);
                isDeleted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public ArrayList<Medium> getAllBooks() {
        return this.mlist;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.append("Books in the shelf: " + this.getAllBooks().size() + "\n");
        for(Medium medium : this.getAllBooks()) {
            strBuilder.append("Title: " + medium.getTitle() + "\n");
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BookShelf bookShelf = new BookShelf();
        //Add two books to the shelf
        Medium medium1 = bookShelf.addMedium("Book 1");
        Medium medium2 = bookShelf.addMedium("Book 2");

        System.out.println(bookShelf.toString());

        //Delete one
        bookShelf.delete(medium1);

        System.out.println(bookShelf.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!